# MVC Model is empty when postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model, **Customer** . When i get the information with an id, it works just fine.

Like ;

/Customer/Entity/5

```
    @model ProgSpace.Models.Customer

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MainLayout.cshtml";
    }

    @section bodypane
    {
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Entity", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



            <div class="col-md-12">


                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>Customer No:</label>
                    <h4># @(Model.ID) </h4>
                </div>



                <div class="clearfix"></div><br />

                <div class="col-md-2">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-12 fileupload fileupload-exists" data-provides="fileupload">

                            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
                                <img src="@Model.Picture.Path" />

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                    <span class="fileupload-new">Add Pic </span>
                                    <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input name="file"  id="file" type="file">
                                </span>
                                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Name *</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    </div>




                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Company</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contact.Company, new { @class = "form-control"})
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Phone </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contact.Phone, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>


                </div>


                <div class="clearfix"><br /></div>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="btn-group">

                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Cancel</button>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        }
    }
```

And in the controller i have these actions.

```
   public ActionResult Entity(int id)
    {
        Customer cust= sis.Customers.Where(t => t.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(cust);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Entity(Customer cust, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            /* Do something */
        }
        else
        {

        }


        return View(cust);
    }
```

When the verb is GET , it's fine. But when i post this form and when the second action (HttpPost action) kicks in , view throws an error..

***Object reference not set to an instance of an object***

which marks the ***Model.ID*** is null in the view.

```
          <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>Customer No:</label>
                    <h4># @(Model.ID) </h4> ---> THIS HERE THROWS NULL EXCEPTION
                </div>
```

I've tried to add a HiddenFor for the Model.ID like

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(t => t.ID)
```

but it didn't change anything.

How do i get back to the same view with the same context again ?

Comment: please check the hidden field value when you page is load all the value put in hidden field after that post.

Comment: Did you add hidden field inside BeginForm block? Also check what model do you pass in cust variable after post action.

Comment: Nayeem Mansoori , before postback hidden field's value was true. it was the id. But after postback, view throws an error that the model's id value is empty.

And Ihor Deyneka, yes the hidden field is in the BeginForm part and both models are the same after and before post...

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the last line of your HttpPost method, what do you have in _cust.ID_?